# json encode array returns empty json object, how to?

Tags: ajax, json, zend-framework, object, each

i am noticing a error when im trying to return json from a fetchAll.

in the controller i have a fetchAction

```
$result = $model->fetchAll();
echo Zend_Json::encode($result);
exit();
```

in a .js file i have a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "/module/index/fetch",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {   
       console.log(data);
       $.each(data, function(index, obj){
          // console.log(obj);
       });
    }
});
```

if i do a `print_r($result);` i get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Module_Model_Module Object
        (
            [_message:protected] => test
            [_created:protected] => 1332188757
            [_dependent_table:protected] => 
        )

    [1] => Module_Model_Module Object
        (
            [_message:protected] => 123123
            [_created:protected] => 1332194812
            [_dependent_table:protected] => 
        )

)
```

but the `console.log(data);` returns 2 empty json objects: `[{},{}]`.

any ideas why i get the json empty back??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that Zend_Json is not able to transform the Module_Model_Module objects into arrays and then into JSON, you could try to call toArray to the objects and see if then Zend_Json can properly encode them